# iOS 5 twitter usage

Tags: ios5

I have a full fledged iPhone application already developed for iOS 5 onwards. I have used a third party library for twitter integration. But it always keeps running into a problem for some reason or the other. How feasible is it to replace all that 3rd party stuff by iOS 5 native twitter functionality?

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement twitter integration you have to import the Social framework on your project and also import it in your .h file

```
#import <Social/Social.h>
```

Then you have to add these lines of code on the method where you want to make a tweet.

```
SLComposeViewController *tweetVC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[tweetVC setInitialText:@"My tweet!"];
[self presentViewController:tweetVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```